# Android AOSP repo init error: OSError [Errno 13] Permission denied

Tags: android-source, repo

I am a little stumped by this error I am getting when trying to `init` an AOSP repository (I've previously been able to use the repo tool to init in the past):

```
aosp@aosp:~/WDIR$ repo init -u https://github.com/khadas/android_manifest.git -b khadas-edge-Qt
warning: gpg (GnuPG) is not available.
warning: Installing it is strongly encouraged.

warning: templates not found /build/git-repo-publish/parts/git/install/usr/share/git-core/templates
Get https://gerrit.googlesource.com/git-repo/clone.bundle
Get https://gerrit.googlesource.com/git-repo
remote: Finding sources: 100% (7/7)
remote: Total 7 (delta 0), reused 7 (delta 0)
Unpacking objects: 100% (7/7), done.
From https://gerrit.googlesource.com/git-repo
   89f3ae5..65f51ad  master     -> origin/master
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/aosp/WDIR/.repo/repo/main.py", line 49, in <module>
    import event_log
  File "/home/aosp/WDIR/.repo/repo/event_log.py", line 167, in <module>
    _EVENT_ID = multiprocessing.Value('i', 1)
  File "/snap/git-repo/18/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/__init__.py", line 253, in Value
    return Value(typecode_or_type, *args, **kwds)
  File "/snap/git-repo/18/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/sharedctypes.py", line 108, in Value
    lock = RLock()
  File "/snap/git-repo/18/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/__init__.py", line 183, in RLock
    return RLock()
  File "/snap/git-repo/18/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/synchronize.py", line 172, in __init__
    SemLock.__init__(self, RECURSIVE_MUTEX, 1, 1)
  File "/snap/git-repo/18/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/synchronize.py", line 75, in __init__
    sl = self._semlock = _multiprocessing.SemLock(kind, value, maxvalue)
OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied
aosp@aosp:~/WDIR$
```

I have tried reinstalling the repo utility, but it didn't help. Any tips?
I am using Ubuntu 20.04 with all the updates installed. This system has been working fine for the past few days, and I have successfully built other images on it. I was able to clone this repository this morning to another dirve on the same machine.

The permissions for the folder where I am making the repo init are as follows:

PS: I have also tried with `sudo` privileges, but nothing. The same issue shows up.

Thanks in advance for your kind help.

EDIT: I have tried on a fresh install of Ubuntu Server 20.04 LTS. Still the same issue is seen.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Found the answer. There are issues with the version up on snapcraft store (more details here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/snapstore-server/+bug/1882296).

As @Wilson-q mentions "The workaround is to remove the snap git-repo package, and install repo directly from the google source site.".

That worked. I wish there was more noise around this however.

Answer (score 2):

You can install it manually.

```
$ mkdir -p ~/.bin
$ PATH="${HOME}/.bin:${PATH}"
$ curl https://storage.googleapis.com/git-repo-downloads/repo > ~/.bin/repo
$ chmod a+rx ~/.bin/repo
```

Answer (score 2):

Check if tmpfs mounted at /dev/shm. if not, just mount it by:

```
mount -t tmpfs tmpfs /dev/shm
```

Answer (score -1):

Modify folder permissions

```
chmod -R 777 folder
```

Comment: Granting full permissions to a directory is usually a bad practice. *If my door-lock is broken and I can't enter my house, one solution is to remove the door, but do I really want to do this?*

Comment: Answer is below. It was not something with permissions. As @NeoAnderson points out, giving full permissions to parts of the filesyste is bad practice and should be avoided if at all possible.